# How can I create a custom control that will change its values (or load the values) based on the language selected?

Tags: c#

Basically, my user control has a label in it and I expose the Text of the label through a property, however when I change the value in UI editor it changes the value for all languages, and does not place it into the resx class. Is there an Attribute or something I need to place on the property to state that it should read/save its value to the .resx file?

Comment: At least you could describe the actual question in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own answer need to add Localizable(true)

Answer (score 1):

As i understood you dont know how to use resources in ASP.NET. So create folder "App_LocalResources" in the same folder as control,  and add resx files with values for each locale that you need.

/App_LocalResources/CustomControl.ascx.resx (Hello - Hello)

/App_LocalResources/CustomControl.ascx.de.resx (Hello - Hallo)

CustomControl.ascx :

```
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Hello%>"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: No this is not quite it, because I want to change value of the label from with in the editor while it is placed on another form. The form creates a Form1.resx and a Form1.de.resx, my question is how do you get the property from the usercontrol to load its value from the Form resource file.

Comment: You can create base class BaseCustomUserControl that inherits from System.Web.UI.UserControl with property and use this property as value for label. Your custom control must inherit it. In the form class you can cast control instance to BaseCustomUserControl and update property value that will update UI value.